# How can I change the text position of connector?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

When I label a connector, the text appears at the midpoint. I can manually change its position. What I basically want to do, is either a) to place the text close to the end (arrow) or b) at its beginning.

I do not want to move all labels manually. So any way how to format all labels at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible in Visio 2010+

[Here](http://pastebin.com/RTni9ZJz) you can take an example file (save it as .vdx and open in Visio 2010)

Right-click context menu "Text orientation" allow you to choose a position of the label along the path.

Comment: I can't access that link inside my corporate firewall, but this appears to use [this custom stencil](http://www.visguy.com/2010/02/09/text-along-a-connectors-path-in-microsoft-visio-2010/)

Comment: @dwurf The visguy's solution covers beginning only, but this question was about the beginning and the end arrow.

Comment: How can one export this shape to use in other Visio files?

Answer (score 26):

As of Visio 2016 use the Text Block function
[image]

Comment: Also works in 2013

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather use the old method, that is predefining where all the labels be automatically, but it seems the whole text block related to the figure (we call labels) are considered a separate object.

Try this out:

Move or rotate text
On a shape
On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click the Text Block tool .
Click the shape to select its text block.
 NOTE    If the text is in a group, click to select the group, and then click to select the text in the shape.

Drag the text to move the text block.
On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click the Pointer Tool .
After you switch back to the Pointer Tool  , the text keeps the same position relative to the shape. If you use the Pointer Tool to drag the text, the shape will also move, even if the text is no longer on the shape. To move the text independently of the shape, use the Text Block tool .

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/add-edit-move-or-rotate-text-on-shapes-HA102749355.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Work around.

Searched for Dynamic Connector in 'Search for Shapes'. 100s of dynamic connectors popped up. Found the yellow handle for moving text to be present in 'Dynamic connector.44'. Boom.

Comment: The question asks how to format all labels at once.  How does this answer that?  (Improve your answer by [edit]ing it.  Do not respond in another comment.)

Comment: Please be aware you are answering a 2-year old question which already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

On older version of Visio (2007) this works:

1. Select the connector
2. Right click on the connector and choose Format > Protection
3. Uncheck the Text option
4. Select the Text Block Tool in the toolbar
5. Reposition the text block